# MySQL Table structure and design- effieciency

Tags: mysql, database

I am currently working with a database in `MyphpAdmin`. There are a total of 9 tables that have been structured to bridge between each other. I am not sure that our table structure is the best and most efficient possible.  I am running a query that only displays `class_caption`, `class_name`, `course_name`, and `class_description`. How can I create a MySQL query that will display all tables bridged together (except `event`)? Also, what modifications should be done to make this tables structure more efficient?

**Basic Query**

```
SELECT  class_name, class_caption, class_credit_hours, class_description
FROM class
```

Comment: MyPhpAdmin or just PhpMyAdmin?

Comment: @Jasper sorry meant PphMyAdmin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First make them normalized. Very difficult to read your picture.
- Create the select statement - use [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) and find the appropriate one for your query.
- Use [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) to see what is going on under the bonnet.
- Ensure that you have the appropriate indexes.

As an aside look up [referential intergrity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_integrity)

Answer (score 0):

You could "left join" table to table. But to be honest is that really what you want? All tables?

Anyway, make sure that each tabke has an unieque id and that each tabke which is going to require information in the other tabke keeps reference to it.

You can do a "select a.*, b.* from tablea a, tableb b where a.id=b.idfroma"